# Discord.js bot doesnt recognise set prefix (which makes everything its prefix)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {Client, Attachment} = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();

const PREFIX = 'z';

bot.on('message', message => {

    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){

case 'general': 
        const general = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('****')
        .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/716968826129874984/720196083858276362/3.gif')
        .setFooter('General Commands...should be straight foward!!!')
        .addField('**** ', ' `prefix | profile | bot info | about | avi` ')
        .setFooter('put "z" behind of each word to open more commands...')
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .setFooter('Made by 11 | discord.gg/PPNyDyw');
        message.channel.send(general);
        break;
```

The prefix is "z", but if i was to type "ngeneral" or put any letter before the command the bot would respond with the command.

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: where are you telling it the prefix is `"z"`? you're defining a constant `PREFIX` but where are you checking that the message starts with it...? the answer to your question is simply "add code to check that the command starts with the prefix"

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the message starts with the prefix. We can use the [startsWith()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) method for this.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) {...}
else {...}
```